# Get value from Javascript to Input type Hidden

Tags: javascript, input, prototypejs, hidden-field, scriptaculous

I am just trying to add code in this javascript to get values of slide to input type="hidden", but i can't get value into input type="hidden", what do I do wrong? Anyway, thanks for your help!

This is javascript code:

```
// <![CDATA[
var hWidth, bWidth;

function setBgPos(v) {
    var off = v * hWidth;
    var pos = -bWidth + (v * bWidth);
    $('slider').setStyle({backgroundPosition: Math.round(pos - off) + 'px'});
}

function setSlideOutput(v) {
    $('percent').innerHTML = Math.round(v * 100) + '%';
}

Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    hWidth = $('slider-handle').getWidth();
    bWidth = $('slider-bar').getWidth();
    var slide = new Control.Slider('slider-handle', 'slider-bar', {
        sliderValue: 0.25,
        onSlide:
            function(v) {
                setBgPos(v);
                setSlideOutput(v);
                $('percentage').value = Math.round(v * 100) + '%';
            },
        onChange:
            function(v) {
                setBgPos(v);
                setSlideOutput(v);
                $('percentage').value = Math.round(v * 100) + '%';
            }
    });
    setBgPos(slide.value);
    setSlideOutput(slide.value);
});
// ]]>
```

Html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="nl">
    <head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<style>
#slider, #slider-bar, #slider-handle {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#slider {
    width: 300px;
    height:42px;
    background: url(img/bg.gif) no-repeat -300px;
    margin-left: 42px;
}
#slider-bar {
    width:300px;
    height:42px;
    background: url(img/track.png) no-repeat;
}
#slider-handle {
    width:42px;
    height:42px;
    cursor:move;
    background: url(img/gripper.png) no-repeat;
}
#percent {
    font-size: 75%;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1.1em;
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="slider">
    <div id="slider-bar">
    <div id="slider-handle"><p id="percent"></p></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="percentage" name="percentage" value="0" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: it is working - http://jsbin.com/ubazod/2/edit . why do you say that it is not ?

Comment: Double check to make sure you only have 1 element with the id "percentage" and maybe add a `console.log()` inside the `onChange`, `onSlide` events to confirm that you are getting values. Another way to set a value on an element is using `setValue()` ie  `$('percentage').setValue(Math.round(v * 100) + '%');`

Comment: @Geek Num 88 , yes, you are right and that was a good tip to start for looking to add value in the javascript, so i did find out how to add value in the javascript and now, it works as well. Thank you very much for your tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Solved to add setvalue, this did help me: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/143329 . Thanks for all the tips guys and more thanks for Geek Num 88!

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$('#percentage')` instead of `$('percentage')`

Comment: @tracevipin Yes, its working, but thats not what i mean. I want to get value of slider into <input type="hidden" value="here valye...">

Comment: No, that doenst matter, because even as you can see, in other id="" is it working and i already did try that before.

Comment: Try using .val instead of .value

Comment: i did and its not working. I did add $('percentage').value = Math.round(v * 100) + '%'; before, but thats not working also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `$('#percentage')[0].value`

What you need is DOM element, not jquery object.

Or, alternatively, use `$('#percentage').val('')`

Comment: Yes, its not jQuery. I don't have to much experience with Scriptaculous, but i want to send value to input hidden to get the value. Can you show example how and where you put that? Thanks

Comment: Use the script you provided, just instead of $('percentage').value = Math.round(v * 100) + '%'; use $('#percentage')[0].value = Math.round(v * 100) + '%';

Comment: Sorry, i got it wrong, thought its jQuery on $. It seems that your script is already correct...